# How can I read from the same serial port in different python scripts?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to make two different scripts read from the same serial port using pyserial. The script that runs after the first script will try to open the port again, which causes an error. I have tried to remove the `s_inst.open()` but that would also cause an error because now it says the port is invalid, because I haven't opened it in the same script.
This is the piece of code I have in both separate scripts (I have also tried this without the if statement, and some other stuff, but I couldn't find anything that would work, I am stuck):

```
s_inst = serial.Serial()
#The microbit's baudrate
s_inst.baudrate = 115200
s_inst.port ='COM3'
if(s_inst.isOpen() == False):
    s_inst.open()
```

Comment: So, basically, no, pyserial won’t let you open the same serial port twice. (Presumably it’s the OS that enforces the restriction). What are you after here?

Comment: @quamrana When I think more about it, it won't work either way. Dangit... I am basically creating a package called 'bitctrl' you can already use it with microbits buttons and tilt, but the buttons and tilts wont work together, which I found out after reading your answer and thinking more about the code.